# libstdc++6 && gcc-9 for ubi8-minimal distro

Tags: docker, dockerfile, ubi

I cannot seem to install gcc-9 or libstdc++6 for ubi8-miniman distro.

```
error: No package matches 'gcc-9'
```

I know there is a `enablerepo=` which I can use to point towards the repo for packages that are not inside the minimal one, but the repos I tried so far were not correct.

Maybe somebody had a similar challenge and solved it?

Comment: we're talking about this image? https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/ubi8/ubi-minimal/5c359a62bed8bd75a2c3fba8?container-tabs=gti

Comment: @RickRackow yep, only in my case its version 8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The minimal base image also only comes with a minimal package manager. As you can read in [RH's blog post on this](https://www.redhat.com/en/blog/introducing-red-hat-universal-base-image) the minimal image has the following:

```
Minimal - Designed for applications that contain their own dependencies (Python, Node.js, .NET, etc.)

Minimized pre-installed content set

No suid binaries

Minimal package manager (install, update, and remove)
```

So you can only install what's available more or less. You can enable and disable repos but only from the following list:

```
# microdnf repolist

(microdnf:155): librhsm-WARNING **: 07:08:39.300: Found 0 entitlement certificates

(microdnf:155): librhsm-WARNING **: 07:08:39.301: Found 0 entitlement certificates
repo id                                                                                                                                                             repo name
ubi-8-appstream-rpms                                                                                                                                                Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - AppStream
ubi-8-baseos-rpms                                                                                                                                                   Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - BaseOS
ubi-8-codeready-builder-rpms                                                                                                                                        Red Hat Universal Base Image 8 (RPMs) - CodeReady Builder
```

You can look up all packages available for those [here](https://cdn-ubi.redhat.com/content/public/ubi/dist/ubi8/8/x86_64/appstream/os/Packages/g/) but there will only be gcc in version 8.5 available.